# Determine the Parity & Cycle Type

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have two permutations

$\tau = (1325)(42567)(1872)(2946)$
$\alpha= (3745)(4659)(6872)$

Which I broke into their disjoint cycles

$\tau = (1847)(3256)$
$\alpha= (1)(237)(468)(59)$

I want to determine the parity and cycle type
of **$\tau^{2}\alpha^{3}\tau\alpha^{-2}$**

Is there a smarter way to do this than just computing it by hand which would take an extremely long time?

Comment: About parity : you can drop $\tau^2$ and $\alpha^{-2}$ because a permutation at an even power is even.

Comment: It won't take an extremely long time, as there are only 9 items being permuted. Just see what the permutation sequence does to each of the 9 items, and write that in cycle notation. Also, it helps that $\alpha^{-2}=(\alpha^2)^{-1}$ and especially $\alpha^{3}$  simplify a bit.